# Canvas Before HTML5: Is backwards compatibility posible / Intercept document.createElement

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an idea...

I am going to try making a JavaScript library which will support backwards compatibility for `canvas` to all browsers prior to HTML5.

I am making the library function as a simple include, where, if `canvas` is not supported, the library takes over and creates support functions for all `canvas` calls, else if `canvas` is supported, the library does nothing. I would like the user to be able to use all `canvas` calls as they would normally with no change in syntax.

I know this sounds crazy, but my thesis is beginning to sound quite feasible, aside from a few hick-ups...

**I somehow need to intercept `document.createElement`** (don't shoot me yet, I'll explain!)

When a call is made to `document.createElement("tagName")`, I need to somehow intercept the function to check the `tagName` parameter for the value of `canvas`.

```
if(canvasNotSupported && tagName === 'canvas')
    tagName = 'img';
```

I will also have to intercept the `document.createElement` function before the return statement to also include functions for the fake canvas such as `getContext', 'toDataURL`, and `toBlob`.

I haven't tried anything along the lines of intercepting the `document.createElement` function yet, but is it possible? Can it be done? How?

**Also**, I will provide a settings variable (Boolean) which will tell my function to override the creation of a `canvas` whether it is supported or not. This should provide full cross-browser compatibility and also make a nifty little work-around for that annoying "tainted canvas through cross origin data" ****-error.

Thanks Everybody!

Comment: How are you planning on building canvas-like functionalities on browsers that don't support the canvas? Functions that should function at least somewhat efficiently...

Comment: Pretty sure libraries like this already exist, though I think they use Flash to "emulate" the canvas.

Comment: @Cerbrus The same way that canvas already exists. With a lot of knowledge in regexp parsing algorithms and binary, anything is possible.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I absolutely hate the idea of using Flash for this, building binary image-source data through regexp will be much, much better. If you know of a library that already does this though, please let me know.

Comment: Note that this approach doesn't provide a meaningful workaround for canvas-taint. It's never possible to read an image that would taint the canvas. If you can read the contents of an image at any point, it's not an image that would taint the canvas. this means that cross-origin (taint-causing) images cannot be included in the dataURL-output of your proposed canvas shim. So, it's true that you could choose not to throw an error, but you would no choice but to exclude tainting images from the data string (because you can't read their contents).

Comment: @apsillers That is a very true statement, and my statement for the workaround was very wishful. As you can guess, if I were to replace the functionality of the canvas, I would also need to be able to retrieve the binary data from an image myself. I have been experimenting with some tests, but I do not wish to state any more about my methods on this subject for it stretches very far from this question's subject matter. Keep in mind, **if the image is able to be displayed, then something was able to grab the binary data of the image.**

Comment: @apsillers Also, if you read the documentation for the "tainetd-canvas" error, 
it is being thrown by Chrome, specifically, due to a possible security exploit.

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

All other browser will allow manipulation of the `image-data`, which shows that the
binary was retrieved, Chrome just doesn't want you to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out!

This may not be the way that the function will be written in the long run, but its a working prototype.

```
//Support for `bind` from MSDN
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}

//Checking for HTML5 canvas support
function time_capsule_canvas_exists()
{
    var elem = time_capsule_canvas_original_document_createElement.call(document, 'canvas');

    if(elem.getContext)
    {
        delete elem;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        delete elem;
        return false;
    }
}

/*Time Capsule Canvas Override value

    @var time_capsule_canvas_override

    Setting this value to true will cause
    time_capsule_canvas to override the
    creation of canvases regardless of
    HTML5 support by the browser
*/
var time_capsule_canvas_override = false;

//Stored original document.createElement
var time_capsule_canvas_original_document_createElement = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function (tag)
{
    var elem;

    if(tag.toLowerCase() === 'canvas' && (!time_capsule_canvas_exists() || time_capsule_canvas_override))
    {
        //tag is 'canvas'
        //Either there is no HTML5 support, or it was explicitly defined to be overriden
        elem = time_capsule_canvas_original_document_createElement.call(document, 'img');

        elem.getContext = function(dimension)
        {
            //Do something
        }.bind(elem);

        elem.toDataURL = function()
        {
            //Do something
        }.bind(elem);

        elem.toBlob = function()
        {
            //Do something
        }.bind(elem);
    }
    else//either non 'canvas' tag, or HTML5 and override not explicitly set
    {
        elem = time_capsule_canvas_original_document_createElement.call(document, tag);
    }

    return elem;
};
```

It works in IE6!!!

Comment: Yea, that's only a wrapper that replaces a canvas with a static image in browsers that don't support the canvas element. This doesn't implement _any_ of the functionality the canvas has. Good luck. Let me give you a suggestion: _"With a lot of knowledge in regexp parsing algorithms and binary, anything is possible."_ <-- That's not how the canvas works.

Comment: @Cerbrus A little salty there buddy, but give it some time to think. I described how I will be implementing this functionality into a library that will imitating `canvas`, not saying that this functionality imitates `canvas` itself. Yes, I am replacing a canvas with an image element, which should give you a good idea of what I am trying to do. Keep your pants on there buddy, but yes, building base64 image-data through parsing binary is the way that canvas works, and with the right algorithms, I can convert an `arcTo` into a base64 image-data string. Hence the image element. Duh! Hahaha!

Comment: I'm sorry @Cerbrus , you've got me heated now, what set you off? Does my code fluster you?

Comment: I mostly meant regexes. they have nothing to do with how the canvas works. I just thing you're _massively_ underestimating the processes involved in emulating an `arcTo` function.

Comment: @Cerbrus Of course `canvas` itself doesn't function using regexp, yet using regexp to create the base64 image data of what would represent the normal output of a `canvas` with calls such as `arcTo` and provide decent speeds. Might I also state, this functionality will provide an "as good as you can get" backwards compatibility to `canvas`. Things such as transparency, which weren't supported in many older browsers, won't be able to be emulated. As well as that, I've had a lot of difficult trying to create the `drawImage` function without using `php`, which is very sad... :(

Comment: @Cerbrus The main reason I am making this is so that sites using `canvas` can provide at least some functionality in older browser instead of simply crashing. Any functionality at that point would be fantastic.